# Interpret TwoMega

Tags: code-golf, interpreter, brainfuck

In this challenge, you will write an interpreter for **2<sup>Ω</sup>** (transcribed as **TwoMega**), a language based loosely on [brainfuck](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck) with an infinite-dimensional storage space.

### The Language

2<sup>Ω</sup> contains three pieces of state:

- The **Tape**, which is an infinite list of bits, all initialized to 0. It has a leftmost element, but no rightmost element.
- The **Memory Pointer**, which is a nonnegative integer that is an index of an element in the tape. A higher memory pointer refers to a tape cell further to the right; a memory pointer of 0 refers to the leftmost element. The memory pointer is initialized to 0.
- The **Hypercube**, which is a conceptually **∞**-dimensional "box" of cells, each of which contains a bit initialized to 0. The width of the Hypercube is bound in every dimension to only 2 cells, but the infinity of dimensions means the number of cells is [uncountable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncountable_set).

An **index** into the hypercube is an infinite list of bits that refers to a cell in the hypercube (in the same way that a finite list of bits could be used to refer to a hypercube of finite dimension). Because the tape is an infinite list of bits, the entire tape always refers to an element of the Hypercube; this element is called the **referent**.

2<sup>Ω</sup> gives meaning to 7 different characters:

- `<` decrements the memory pointer by 1. Decrementing it below 0 is undefined behavior, so you do not need to handle it.
- `>` increments the memory pointer by 1.
- `!` flips the bit at the referent.
- `.` outputs the bit at the referent.
- `^` replaces the bit at the cell pointed to by the memory pointer on the tape with the *inverse* of the bit at the referent.
- `[x]` runs the code `x` as long as the bit at the referent is 1.

### The Challenge

Your task is to write a program that takes a string as input and executes that input as a 2<sup>Ω</sup> program.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest valid answer (measured in bytes) wins.

### Notes

- You can assume that the program will consist solely of the characters `<>!.^[]` and that `[]` will be properly nested.
- Your interpreter should only be limited by available memory on the system. It should be able to run the sample programs in a reasonable amount of time.

### Sample Programs

Print 1:

```
!.
```

Print 010:

```
.!.!.
```

Print 0 forever:

```
![!.!]
```

Print 0 forever, or 1 forever if `!` is prepended:

```
[.]![!.!]
```

Comment: A small note: the number of storage cells is not actually uncountable, as the number of `1`s on the tape is always finite. In fact, there is a fairly simple bijection between the natural numbers and the tape states (interpret the tape contents as a backwards binary number), which shows that the Hypercube is basically an infinite 1D array, accessed by _flipping bits_ in an integer pointer value, instead of in/decrementing as in brainfuck.

Comment: Also, re: your invitation to write a `cat` program: there doesn't seem to be an instruction for taking input.

Comment: I think there should be sample programs using more of the instruction set.Two simple ones:  `.` - prints a single zero and then exists; `!^!.` - prints a single one then exits. More would be good though. At the moment one must understand submissions in order to verify them (and hence upvote them!)

Comment: @Lynn The input would be given by having either a 1 or a 0 on cell `[0,0,0,0,0,0,0...]` (i.e. the presence of a `!` at the start of the program).

Comment: Then you could do `[.]![!.!]` to print the value of that cell forever

Comment: But the set of reachable cells are countable.

Comment: inb4 a 2000 byte BF program

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 148 bytes

```javascript
x=>eval(x.replace(e=/./g,c=>({'<':'u/=2','>':'u*=2','!':'e[v]^=1','.':'alert(+!!e[v])','^':'v=(v|u)^u*e[v]','[':'while(e[v]){'}[c]||'}')+';',v=u=1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hc1BDoMgEAXQfW/BakAtxi5rx6WXIJoQSqwNEaNCTdSzU3T3/8vPzFd6OaupH5f7YN86SKOnBZUdZms0N7a71RhWrLSXhq580qORSlONOc@7TGFFN3jBE1yOD8igOmNyRRKjFr5psYiNx3bdpikhJ7OIbUSP1O@OtS45NaKI@Pv0Jj45ZxscQjX7DgewFErIPDosGAtlTYEIwkkDLPwB)

## It's turing complete

```javascript
BoolFuck TwoMega
< >^>^>[!]^<<<<[!]^>>[!]!^>[!]!^>[!]!^<<<<(>^>^>1<<<<1>>0>0>0<<<<)
> ^<^<[!]^>>>>[!]^<<[!]!^<[!]!^<[!]!^>>>(^<^<1>>>>1<<0<0<0>>>)
```

Need init as moving right few places and init the current and right one bit of the address as 1 (`>>>>>>>>^>^<`)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY69boQwEIT7PIVdrX1wRpcy2JRXpLgUKRGWLOIQIgtO/DgXAc9O1oQCF@uZb2Ytfxtv@rKr78O5aT/sapztBlW2Td86K1xbPV3V@lCZ9caxh@js3ZnSskQkVVyqjE0g4QXGRD1DDFmQp01SlDb3hVYXdALd9jKLKA2YI9QIvWJ@HrkeT4EizBH@fNXOsq02ISoQLbDkZTHPADyC9PA95qPX97eb6Ieubqr685dZHo08hdirUV1iq6aF8zW9Msj2ozMtCRFESy1zWujAwi2Do/o4MSEUq2Fn78h95z8/zBARAXz9Aw)

Place `n` in BoolFuck is written as `(0, 0, ..., 0(n*0), [1], 1, 0, 0, ...)`.

For `>`, it does `n` => `n+1`

```javascript
     0 0 0 0 0[1]1 0 0 0 0
^    0 0 0 0 0[x]1 0 0 0 0
<    0 0 0 0[0]x 1 0 0 0 0
^    0 0 0 0[y]x 1 0 0 0 0, yx != 01
<    0 0 0[0]y x 1 0 0 0 0
[!]^ 0 0 0[1]y x 1 0 0 0 0, (0yx10) = 0
>>>> 0 0 0 1 y x 1[0]0 0 0
[!]^ 0 0 0 1 y x 1[1]0 0 0, (1yx10) = 0
<<   0 0 0 1 y[x]1 1 0 0 0
[!]! 0 0 0 1 y[x]1 1 0 0 0, (1yx11) = 1
^    0 0 0 1 y[0]1 1 0 0 0
<    0 0 0 1[y]0 1 1 0 0 0
[!]! 0 0 0 1[y]0 1 1 0 0 0, (1y011) = 1
^    0 0 0 1[0]0 1 1 0 0 0
<    0 0 0[1]0 0 1 1 0 0 0
[!]! 0 0 0[1]0 0 1 1 0 0 0, (10011) = 1
^    0 0 0[0]0 0 1 1 0 0 0
>>>  0 0 0 0 0 0[1]1 0 0 0
```

Same to how `<` work

Comment: Are you sure this translation is valid? `!>.` prints `1` in boolfuck but translates to `!>^.` which prints 1 in TwoMega (`>` does not affect the tape; `^` does not affect the tape since the referent is 1)

Comment: @EsolangingFruit `+>;` do `[1]00...` `1[0]0...` (output 0), `!>^.` do `(0,0,...)=1, ptr=([0],0,...)` `(0,0,...)=1, ptr=(0,[0],...)` `(0,0,...)=1, ptr=(0,[1],...)` (output 0), what's wrong?

Comment: @EsolangingFruit for `!>.`, only `>` is a valid command in boolfuck...

Comment: @l4m2 In TwoMega, `!` inverts the referent, not the tape cell.

Comment: @EsolangingFruit so what's wrong here?

Comment: I think your code for `^` is wrong, it should be something like `e[v]?v&=~u:v|=u`.

Comment: seems i misunderstood the problem

Comment: @l4m2 Looks like your translation contains a few `1` and `0`. What are those supposed to mean?

Comment: @EsolangingFruit the string before `(` has no `1` and `0`. Number mean set the current place to `1` or `0`, possibly destroy the current placeinfo

Comment: I'd appreciate if you were to put an explanation of how the translation works.

Comment: This site is for programming contests and challenges. General programming questions are off-topic here. You may be able to get help on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 167 bytes

```python
t=h=I=0
m=1
E=''
for c in input():i='[<>!.^]'.find(c);E+=' '*I+'while+2**t&h: m/=2 m*=2 h^=2**t print+(2**t&h>0) t=t&~m|m*(2**t&h<1) #'.split()[i]+'\n';I-=~-i/5
exec E
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY7LCoMwFET3fsWtBa8m@IRu1OvOhd9gdWOVBEwUm9IWir9ulRaGszgMzMxvIyadbJshQRVFlqLYKgnRGqYFOpB6z/wwrpdKwjovTkHbYDBIfXM7Lys5ISCrOD6FHHueMGYckYIKKQHFdoiWDgnzIrXh7q9QRB4YMs6qPor9XR57cMbgPo9yX6tlw/GqMat8Wn0ZXqz@1XdQbpu9PwhO9YHG/gI)

**t** is the tape. **t = 6** means the tape is [0 1 1 0 0 0 …]

**m** is 2 to the power of the memory pointer. So **m = 8** means we're pointing at tape bit 3.

**h** is the hypercube. **h = 80** (bits 4 and 6 set) means the bits at [0 0 1 0 …] and [0 1 1 0 …] are set.

To read the bit at the referent, we check **2<sup>t</sup> & h**. To flip it, we perform **h ^= 2<sup>t</sup>**.

We translate the instructions to Python code and execute the result. **I** stores the indentation level of the while loops.

Comment: Either your program or the second test case is wrong

Comment: @wastl The second test case was wrong. ;)

Comment: [Some rearrangements, extra variable for `2**t`](https://tio.run/##FY2xCoMwFAB3v@LVgs8kVKvQRfvcHPwGq4tVEjBR2pSmUPrrNsJxwy23fqxcTL5tliQ1dA40OcqCmhCDaXnAAMp41peNWaEIr9Uh6TtMJmXu8cDKWhAC8kagTikHzb1kTw7WhzJWxC6S1ZmBJRv99FfzPVwzVjrKObdwhLdU8yh8LTB5rrPyn1Z1Am8Gy@ZEKr0EoxsHqLct9Ovk0O7qwj8) (-6 bytes).

Answer (score 1):

## [Brain-Flak Classic](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 816 bytes

```
<>(((<(())>)))<>{(([][][])(((({}){}[])({}))({})[]([][](({})(({}())(({}){}{}({}(<()>))<{<>({}<>)}{}>))))))(([]{()(<{}>)}{}){<((<{}>))<>(()(){[](<{}>)}{}<{({}[]<({}<>)<>>)}{}{}>)<>({()<({}<>)<>>}<<>{<>(({}){}<>({}<>)[])<>}{}<>({()<({}[]<<>({}<>)>)>}{})<>(({})<<>{({}[]<({}<>)<>>)}({}<>)<>{({}<>)<>}>)<>>)<>({}<>)<>>}{}([]{()(<{}>)}{}){{}<>({})(<>)}{}([]{()(<{}>)}{}){(<{}<>({}<{((<({}[])>))}{}{((<(())>))}{}>)<>>)}{}([]{()(<{}>)}{}){(<{}<>({}<({}())>)<>>)}{}([]{()(<{}>)}{}){(<{}<>[({})]<>>)}{}([]{()(<{}>)}{})<{((<{}>))<>{}({}<{<>(({}){}<>({}<>)[])<>}{}<>({()<({}[]<<>({}<>)>)>}{})<>(((){[](<{}>)}{})<<>{({}[]<({}<>)<>>)}{}(<>)<>{({}<>)<>}>)<>>)<>({}<>)<>}{}(<>)<>{({}<>)<>}{}>()){((({}[]<>){(<{}({}<>)>)}{}())<{({}<({}<>)<>((((((([][][]){}){}){}()){}){}({})())[][])>{[](<{}>)}{}{()(<{}>)}{})}{}({}<>)>[]){{}(<>)}}{}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVLLagMxDPyW3qRD@gXCP7I4sA0UQpcemqPQt7szsp1HkzZQ77IrS/LMSPLb13r83L1v60drVkTERFSLqlpxkaXyUfjFQz1ow8jPUjOcEX5wbmTBxmtCHHPAelhRuImrTFuqi4rREzwC1twoNaioA3dGzYXE1lGspJMxAote/GHQTIAUMWkh2Ur0fc8G1gziIf84xPN3XNP0aUQPTAgSo9qfFQ0BcKXjLk6zQzibnq1F/SztMoRR5jOE3vxnmQvl1F9yUsWYQI7P/t/J2/E97irvx99dfZACRNTpeRkBV3plkz@yC3lbzkzS17jGWY1mWv9zPqoZK9eab1oTZwpCdFUBZ7S2L1wvi@1fa9ut22FbT6fj4Rs)

This code was written just so I'd have a place to write a proof of Turing-completeness.

### Proof of Turing-completeness

We show a reduction from Boolfuck to TwoMega:

```
Boolfuck   TwoMega
>          >>
<          <<
.          !^!.!^!
[          !^![!^!
]          !^!]!^!
+          !^[!]^[>!^<[!]!^>[!]!^<]
```

This translation stores the Boolfuck state in the even-numbered tape cells in TwoMega.  All of the translated commands will preserve the following invariants:

- The memory pointer is at an even-numbered cell.
- All odd-numbered tape cells are zero.
- For any possible tape with all odd-numbered cells zero, the corresponding value on the hypercube is zero.

The snippet `!^!` will keep `[0]0` constant and swap between `0[0]` and `[1]1` (where attention is limited to the line on the hypercube reachable without moving the memory pointer).  As such, it is used to temporarily put the current tape value into the referent for the Boolfuck commands which care about it.

If TwoMega were given an input command `,` with the expected semantics, the Boolfuck command `,` would translate to `>^<,!^>[!]!^<`.  Since `,` is not necessary to prove that Boolfuck is Turing-complete, the lack of an input command does not affect this proof.

Comment: It mainly stores info in the position in the hypercube rather than the cube itself?

Comment: @l4m2 My reduction from BoolFuck does not store any data in the cube itself.  Any 1s I make on the hypercube are only there to set tape cells to 0.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>297</s> <s>284</s> 274 bytes

*-10 bytes thanks to ovs and Jonathan Allan*

```python
C=input()
h={}
t=set()
def f(C,p):
 c=C[0];r=hash(frozenset(t));v=h.get(r,0)
 p={"<":p-1,">":p+1}.get(c,p)
 if'"'>c:h[r]=not v
 if"."==c:print(int(v))
 if"]"<c:t.discard(p)if v else t.add(p)
 if"["==c:
  while f(C[1:],p):1
 else:return c=="]"and v or C and f(C[1:],p)
f(C,0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY@7jsMgEEV7vmJME1C8lq3tSCaNP8NyYfFYkCKMMPFqN8q3O0CTYjSvM1d3wl@yq/8@jhGdD4/EOLH4fJGEmy6N0gYMG9vABQGJ49TPl4h22Swzcf3XvmCJ88uOtvvJdWx7TiDgk16pCF9DS285n4dX3cosRMCZEz3dpLBTnNGvCfYyox1FlCJE5xMrsfPK0plepUidcptcomKBOwM76PumIXWLKpPKTfWeAPxad9fF9jSIuVgfSMVF1OkRff4Ds@jiVZZZI4xQyg9OysM9P45marpmfgM)

Comment: `t.discard(p)` -> `t-={p}`

Comment: @shooqie That doesn't work unless `t` is `global`.

Comment: @fergusq Though I'm pretty sure it works if you declare `f` as `f(C,p,t=set())`

Answer (score 0):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), <s>75</s> 71 bytes

```
lPB0aR:^"!><[].^_""!:_
--viPU0
++v
W_{
}
O_
i@v:!_LFBilPB0
l@FBi"^n;Vau
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/J8DJIDHIKk5J0c4mOlYvLl5JSdEqnktXtywzINSAS1u7jCs8vpqrlss/nivTocxKMd7HzSkTpIsrxwHIUorLsw5LLP3//3@cHQgoRtvE6cUCAA)

Translates the 2<sup>Ω</sup> code into equivalent Pip code and evaluates it.

We use `i` to represent the tape, `v` for the tape pointer*, and `l` for the hypercube. The first two come preinitialized to useful values; `l` starts as `[]`, to which we push a `0` (`lPU0`) to avoid indexing-empty-list problems.

<sup>* Actually, it's the bitwise negation of the tape pointer, because we're storing the tape backwards for easier conversion to decimal.</sup>

The rest of the code is:

```
aR:...;     Do a bunch of replacements in a, translating it into Pip code
       Va   Evaluate a
         u  Suppress output of the final expression that was evaluated
```

The translation table:

```
!  !:_
>  --viPU0
<  ++v
[  W_{
]  }
.  O_
^  i@v:!_LFBilPB0
_  l@FBi
```

`l@FBi` is the referent: element of hypercube `l` at the index (convert `i` from binary). It appears often, so we call it `_` and replace `_` with the real code at the end.

- `!:_` logically negates the referent in place.
- `--viPU0` decrements `v` (moving the tape pointer to the right); it then pushes another `0` to the left side of `i`, to make sure that the tape pointer stays in bounds.
- `++v` increments `v` (no need for bounds-checking, per OP).
- `W_{` runs a loop while the referent is truthy (i.e. nonzero, i.e. `1`).
- `}` closes the loop.
- `O_` outputs the referent without newline.

Finally, for `^`:

```
i@v:            Set the current tape cell to
    !_          The logical negation of the referent
                Now, make sure the list representing the hypercube is long enough:
      LFBi      Loop frombinary(i) times:
          lPB0  Push another 0 to the end of l
                This ensures that FBi will always be a valid index into l
```